# Solution to resolve "Could not add MANIFEST.MF to ZIP" error in GRADLE

Tags: java, gradle, build, manifest.mf

I am using gradle to build a JAVA project. This java project contains 2 jar tasks. The other jar task creates a Manifest.MF. The 2nd Jar task does not. It gives and error "Could not add MANIFEST.MF to ZIP" when it is trying to build. I am not customizing the manifest.mf file. It is he default file created by gradle.

I've looked on overflow and gradle at ways to manipulate the manifest.mf but no such luck yet.

Here is the code for the task that gives the error(all other tasks work fine):

```
task ejbJar(type: Jar) {
    description = "This task is to build the ytd EJB.JAR file for zzz."
    rootSpec.exclude("**/*.sig","**/config/*.xml")
    rootSpec.filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [VERSION: versNumber, BUILD: buildNumber, HTTPSECURE: httpsecure])
    archiveFileName = "${ytd}_ejb.jar"

    //includes the class files into the JAR
    from(sourceSets.main.output) {
        include "**"
    }

    //replace tokens in xml files
    //includes the xml files inside of the config folder in the jar files
    from('src/main/resources/com/foo/config') {
        include '*.xml'
        into 'com/foo/config'
        filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [VERSION: versNumber, BUILD: buildNumber, HTTPSECURE: httpsecure])
    }

    from('src/main/webapp/META-INF') {
        into "/META-INF"
        include("*ejb*.xml")
    }

    from('src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes') {
        into '/'
        include('**/*')
        exclude('zzz1.properties', 'zzz2.properties')
    }



}
```

I would like the task to compile and create the manifest.mf file inside the jar.

Comment: I figured it out. The line: ```rootSpec.filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [VERSION: versNumber, BUILD: buildNumber, HTTPSECURE: httpsecure])``` was the problem. Not exactly sure why though.